# calculate permutation for large number

Tags: java, permutation

I am using this java code to try to calculate the permutations of 20:
(this is just code part used for calculating permutation)

```
int[] myArray = new int[20];
for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    myArray[i] = i + 1;

List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int index = 0; index < myArray.length; index++)
{
    intList.add(myArray[index]);
}

List<Integer> vals = intList; 

Collection<List<Integer>> orderPerm = Collections2.permutations(vals);
```

but of course there is no enough memory for that;

any suggestions?

Comment: assign more memory to the program?

Comment: java -Xmx15g -jar  (was not enough and I think maybe I am missing something in the code or there is better way)

Comment: You know there would be 2432902008176640000 permutations that array http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php?n=20&r=20&action=solve

Comment: I thought parallelism could work, but perhaps memory still is an issue. I think this might help you though, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-level_parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

There would be **2432902008176640000** of those permutations. http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/discretemathematics/permutations.php?n=20&r=20&action=solve

If you could output 100 000 of permutations per second it would take 
2432902008176640000 / 100000 / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 = **771468 years** to do it

**100M** permutations per second would be faster and take just **771 years**

Answer (score 0):

The number of permutations of size 20 is 20 factorial, which turns out to be around 10^18. 8 gigabytes of ram are approximately 8 * 10^9 bytes, which as you might understand, is much below the amount of storage needed to store every possible permutations out of the 10^18.

Comment: actually I know but, there is no way to do such calculation? :(

Comment: You just can't store them in an array/list. You might come up with some clever solution, such as an iterator that only stores 1 permutation at any given moment, and use a .next() method to get the next one and so on, so you won't have to store all of the permutations at the same time.

Comment: Or you could just buy 44254229TB of memory :)   (= 2432902008176640000*20 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 )

Answer (score 0):

Well the less memory approach will involve calculating a fixed but manageable number of permutations on demand. So, you will require a method like getNextPermutation().

I found the method from Collection2.java from Guava's source(the one that you are currently using in your code):
https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.java

You have,

```
@Override
    protected List<E> computeNext() {
      if (nextPermutation == null) {
        return endOfData();
      }
      ImmutableList<E> next = ImmutableList.copyOf(nextPermutation);
      calculateNextPermutation();
      return next;
    }

    void calculateNextPermutation() {
      int j = findNextJ();
      if (j == -1) {
        nextPermutation = null;
        return;
      }

      int l = findNextL(j);
      Collections.swap(nextPermutation, j, l);
      int n = nextPermutation.size();
      Collections.reverse(nextPermutation.subList(j + 1, n));
}
```

You can call this compute next say 100 or 1000 times at once and store the results.

On your part, you will have to fork the source and modify calling of methods here and there a bit to make it as you want.